# Can't access database on production instance

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, database-connection

Everything works fine when I have my application on my local server, but I can't access the database on the production instance.
The index page loads with no problems (no DB access is required there).
As soon as I click to a page which needs DB access, I get an error message:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in /home/... line 48**.
Here is the code it fails on:

```
47: $query = $this->db->get($table_name);
48: return $query->result_array();
```

I deliberately changed the *database.php* file so that my DB credentials were **incorrect**, and had the same issue. I'm almost certain the credentials are correct though.
Is there somewhere else that affects the database connection?
Like the *.htaccess*?

Comment: Make sure you're connecting using the correct mysql port. It's not always default on prod.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed the port number and still have the same problem. I tried to change *$db['default']['db_debug']* to **TRUE** and I got an error message saying that the Loader failed.

Comment: This does not seem like an connection eror. I'd say that the DB class is not instantiated. If you just moved (or updated) the files to the production server, check if the files and folders have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help with this!
I found the problem. It was indeed a database connectivity issue, but was a rookie mistake.

I thought that the *$config['hostname']* should be the url of the website. But instead, it was just **localhost**. Hopefully nobody makes this silly mistake again.

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
```